# How to connect DisMax handler solr?

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, full-text-search

How should I configure `solrconfig.xml` for connecting DisMax plugin? I need it to use full-text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example search handler which specifies DisMax as its search handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/simpleQuery" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str> <!-- this is how you specify DisMax -->
        <str name="qf">Title^2 Body</str> <!-- The fields (and their weightings) to search in.-->
        <str name="rows">500</str>
        <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```